Correct practice to shutdown ROS Python Nodes
What is the correct way to shutdown ROS2 Python nodes?
def main():
    rclpy.init()
    node = TestNode()
    rclpy.spin(node)
    node.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()

Should the class TestNode() have a dedicated shutdown function? If so a simple self.destroy_node()?
Furthermore, If I had multiple nodes running, for example 'node2' in different files. Is it appropriate to create a service with a callback function to shutdown node2 within node2 that 'node' is a client of?
So my shutdown function call send 'Empty' requests to each running nodes shutdown service, to close of nodes and exit the whole process cleanly!
